# Intersection function in Scala

Tags: scala

The problem is：

> Intersection: Given two (singly) linked lists, determine if the two
>   lists intersect. Return the intersecting node. Note that the
>   intersection is defined based on reference, not value.
>
> That is, if the kth node of the first linked list is the exact same
>   node (by reference) as the jth node of the second linked list, then
>   they are intersecting. Below is an example:

[image]
The code I wrote is as following, may I know any improvement can be done?

```
  def intersecton[A](alist: List[A], blist:List[A]): Option[A]= (alist.last, blist.last)match{
    case (a,b) if (a!=b) => None
    case (_,_) if (alist.size>1 && blist.size>1 && alist(alist.size-2) != blist(blist.size-2)) => Some(alist.last)
    case (a,b) if (alist.size ==1||blist.size ==1)&& a==b => Some(a)
    case (_,_) => intersecton(alist.dropRight(1), blist.dropRight(1))
  }
```

Below is the test case I already run:

```
val list1: List[Int]=List(5,6, 1, 1, 4)
val list2: List[Int]=List(6, 1, 1,4)
>>6 

val list1: List[Int]=List(3,2,4)
val list2: List[Int]=List(5,6,7)
>>None


val list1: List[Int]=List(4,6,7)
 val list2: List[Int]=List(5,6,7)
>>6
```

Comment: Have you tested this code? If you believe that it works correctly, please show a few test cases.

Comment: I have tested @200_success

Comment: Also, what is an "`intersecton`"?

Comment: I have updated the description, let me know it is clear, thanks

Comment: The code is broken according to the description as outlined in 200_success's answer. The main problem here is the `case (_,_) => intersection ...` statement. Incorrectly both lists are shortened here. Accordingly this question is off-topic by our standards. For more information, see the [help/on-topic]

Comment: @Vogel612 The code was broken, but the test cases demonstrate that the author was unaware of the bug. It's OK to discuss correctness in unanticipated cases.

Answer (score 6):

`intersecton(List(1, 2, 4), List(4, 5, 6))` incorrectly returns `None`.

---

You've asked several questions recently, and I keep seeing similar issues:

- **Using `list.last`**: You have been advised to [avoid traversing to the end of the list](/a/148887/9357), for efficiency.  Lists should be manipulated at the head.
- **Functional thinking**: These solutions involve too many tedious cases, and the code could be simplified by [defining helper functions](/a/148881/9357), or even [restated entirely in terms of other functions](/a/148886/9357).
- **Spelling**: What's an "intersecton"?  (You previously [misspelled "palindrome"](/q/148883/9357), twice.)
- **Inadequate testing**: The counterexample cited above just happened to be the first test I tried, and it failed.  This isn't the first time I've seen an [obviously wrong result](/a/148881/9357).  Your [first question](/questions/148710/partition-the-list-function-in-scala#comment279749_148710) was closed due to broken code, and it still hasn't been fixed.

You are welcome to use Code Review as a learning resource, but it would be a good idea to show some improvement between questions.

Comment: intersecton(List(1, 2, 4), List(4, 5, 6)) incorrectly returns Non? Then, what do you think it should return?

Comment: @sweetyBaby it should return 4. because the 2nd index in list one is reference-equal to the 0th index in list two. I have elaborated a bit in a comment on your question

Comment: @Vogel612, nope, maybe I did not describe very clearly, it should be none , I edited the problem description, thanks

Comment: Even with your added explanation, the answer should still be 4. The lists still intersect, and the question doesn't say that degenerate intersections should be prohibited.

Comment: @200_success I thought you misunderstand the problem, *Note that the intersection is defined based on reference, not value*, it is the reference not just the value, if it should be 4, then following part should be the same, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated code for this problem:

```
def intersection[A](alist: List[A], blist:List[A]): List[A]= {
    alist.intersect(blist)
}
```